# JavaScript Regex: Number of trailing newlines in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find the number of trailing newlines in a string. Consider the following example:

```
var foo = 'bar \n fooo \n   \n   \n';
```

For `foo` i should get back 3, meaning it won't count the newline between bar and fooo.

The way that I'm doing it right now is matching all trailing whitespaces `/\s*$.` and then matching `/\n/g` against the result to get the exact number. While this works, I was wondering if there is a way to do it with only one regular expression. Thanks for you help!

P.S.

Assume that all newlines are normalized to `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `/\s+$/` to find all trailing whitespace, then count the number of `\n` found in that string.

For example:

```
var foo = 'bar \n fooo \n   \n   \n';
var trailingLines = foo .match(/\s+$/)[0].split('\n').length - 1;
```

Alternatively, you could use a lookahead in a pattern like this:

```
/\n(?=\s*$)/g
```

This will match any `\n` which is followed by zero or more whitespace characters and the end of the string.

For example:

```
var foo = 'bar \n fooo \n   \n   \n';
var trailingLines = foo.match(/\n(?=\s*$)/g).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

(\s*\n\s*)+$

\s* matches zero or more whitespaces

'your string here'.match(/(\s*\n\s*)+$/g).length;

Comment: This code doesn't work. `'bar \n fooo \n   \n   \n'.match(/(\s*\n\s*)+$/g).length` returns 1, but OP expects 3.